# std::move data out of Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to do an std::move, or the moral equivalent, of the data inside a dynamically sized Eigen::Matrix? I want to move the data out for use in my own API.

Comment: No you can't because the [raw data array is a private member](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/bd82ba5212edecf0434d30a74e1f0f42625fe582/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h#L185).  Unless you modify the Eigen source to get a reference to the pointer you are out of luck.

Comment: @HenriMenke Apparently there are variations of the matrix class with [dynamic and fixed-size](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title8) allocation. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/bd82ba5212edecf0434d30a74e1f0f42625fe582/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h#L139) of the Matrix base class, the Storage is not dynamically allocated but a simple data member, and so is by extension `data`. You can do anything you want with it but it goes away with the matrix. There is no way to obtain ownership of the data itself.

Comment: Would allocating the storage on your own and using an `Eigen::Map` on that data be an option?

Comment: Maybe another option is to simply get a pointer to the Matrix's data (using `mat.data()`, it's read-write) and keep `mat` in life until you don't need this data anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not clarify what you actually want to do, a more generic answer:

**No**, there is no way to move the data out of an `Eigen::Matrix` without accessing internals of Eigen (e.g., if you inherit from `Eigen::Matrix` you have access to all internal data). I will not elaborate on how to do this, since this could break anytime if the internals of Eigen change.

There are generally two "correct" ways (or a combination of those) to interact with different APIs:

1. Use Eigen objects for data storage and get read-write access to the internal data using the [`.data()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#ac54123f62de4c46a9107ff53890b6116) function.
2. Use your own API for data storage, and use `Eigen::Map` to access that data from Eigen's side: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html